# How do I bind the Overlay Tool for new Ajax elements in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, data-binding, binding, overlay

I'm using:

```
echo $javascript->link('tools.overlay-1.0.4', false);
```

which is initialized with:

```
$(".overlay_popup").overlay({
    expose: '#000000',
    close: '.close_overlay',
    finish: {
        top: 'center',
        left: 'center',
        absolute: false
    }
});
```

I call the overlay popup box like this:

```
echo $html->link(
    "add part",
    array('controller'=>'garage_parts',
        'action'=>'addfrompartlist',
        $gcar['GarageCar']['id'],
        $gcar['GarageCar']['car_id']),
    array('class'=>'js-ajax overlay_popup',
        'id'=>'add_part_overlay',
        'rel'=>'.overlay_container')
);
```

This all works fine and dandy, however I have an ajax function that dynamically adds the "add part" hyperlink button shown above and I have no idea how to bind this new button to the overlay.  Normally, I would use something like this:

`$(".overlay_popup").bind("click", function(){...` but this didn't work for the overlay.  Any ideas on how I can successfully do this?

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to try for dynamically added links, inspired by Csongor:

```
var Overlay = $(".overlay_popup").data("overlay");
$(".overlay_popup").overlay(Overlay.getConf());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the API.load in the click event?

http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay.html

```
var overlayDiv = $(".overlay_popup").overlay({expose: '#000000', close: '.close_overlay',   finish: { top: 'center', left: 'center', absolute: false }});
```

$(".overlay_popup").bind("click", function(){overlayDiv.load();})

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery live( type, fn ) method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

`$(".overlay_popup").live("click", function(){...})` binds your handler to all currently matched elements but also to all new elements, which match your selector, too.

Comment: well .live does not work in my website at all for some reason.  I originally tried that instead of bind but was only able to get bind to work. This however is not an issue.  The problem is that the overlay is not a "click" state.  I think the above $(".overlay_popup").overlay({}) needs to be set up before the element is clicked on.  So one issue is I have no idea what state to bind it to.... and the other issue is whether the function just contains the $(".overlay_popup").overlay({}). I think I tried all these variations and nothing worked.

Comment: `live` was introduced with jquery 1.3, so check that you're still not using 1.2.6?

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution, sorry for my bad english...

this is de solution:

in the librarie tools.overlay-1.1.2.js add the next code before of function overlay():

```
 $.fn.addObjectToOverlay = function(element, confOverlay){
  el = new Overlay($(element), confOverlay);
  instances.push(el);
  $(this).data("overlay", el);
 };

 // jQuery plugin initialization
 $.fn.overlay = function(conf) {
```

then you have to call the function like this

```
$('#avisoFav').remove();
$video = $(respuesta);
$video.css("display", "none");
$("#contenidoFav").append($video);
$.each($video.find('.linkRMTP'), function (index, obj){
 $video.addObjectToOverlay(obj, confOverlay);
});
$video.slideDown('fast');
```

the variable "confOverlay" is the configuration of my overlay,  example:

```
confOverlay = { 
   effect: 'drop', 
   expose: '#789',
   top:25,
   closeOnClick : false,
   fastInSpeed : 'fast',
   onBeforeLoad: function(){
    idVideo = $(this.getTrigger()).attr("idVideo");
    idiomaActual = $(this.getTrigger()).attr("idiomaActual");
    onBeforeLoad(idVideo, idiomaActual);
   },
   onLoad: function(){
    $("#contenedorVideo > *").remove();
    url= $(this.getTrigger()).attr('link');
    onLoaded(url);
   },
   onClose: function (){
    $("#contenedorVideo > *").remove();
   }
  };
```

so thats all that you have to do for the overlay worked with new create elements in real time.

Atte.
Salvador Romero

Comment: I have responded with comment above

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answers late change the function with this code

```
$.fn.addObjectToOverlay = function(element, confOverlay){ 
    if ($.isFunction(confOverlay)) {
        conf = {onBeforeLoad: confOverlay}; 
    }

    var globals = $.extend({}, $.tools.overlay.conf); 
    confOverlay = $.extend(true, globals, confOverlay);
    el = new Overlay($(element), confOverlay);
    instances.push(el);
    $(this).data("overlay", el);
    return confOverlay.api ? el: this;
};
```